# A chicken and egg problem with Spring Cloud Config Client and Server when BOTH are mTLS enabled?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-config

Small question regarding Spring Cloud Config Client and Server, especially in the scenario when BOTH are mTLS enabled.

First of all, the server. On server side, since he is the first that has to be up, server has in properties file, the keystore and truststore, alongside passwords, in order to start mTLS.

Now, the client. The reason to chose Spring Cloud Config in the first place is that we can store properties in git, Vault, etc...

That way, the property file of client should be super light, just enough information to connect to the server, such as just `spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888`

However, when mTLS is enabled at server side, then, by definition, the client needs the proper keystore and truststore (that is store in Git, Vault)

This is I believe a chicken end egg problem, since:
In order to start the client, client needs to retrieve the keystore and truststore and password  from Git, Vault, by connecting to the server.

But in order to connect to the server, it needs keystore and truststore and password.

Currently, it can work if on client side, the basic property file has

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
server.ssl.key-alias=
server.ssl.key-password=
server.ssl.key-store-password=
server.ssl.key-store-provider=
server.ssl.key-store-type=
server.ssl.key-store=
server.ssl.trust-store-password=
server.ssl.trust-store-provider=
server.ssl.trust-store-type=
server.ssl.trust-store=
```

But this is kinda defeating the purpose of Spring Cloud Config, since most of the properties are still in the property file.

What is the correct way to achieve a Client having only to have the server location, and all other information, such as the keystore and truststore and password to still remain inside Git, Vault, etc?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Spring Team, nothing can be done.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1867